# Why does my compiler interpret a struct return as an int return in C?

Tags: c

i'm writing a little game in c where i construct the player as a struct named "ch", using constructPlayer function in a player.c file, returning a struct variable named "player".
But when i call this function to assign a struct ch player variable, it says that the return of constructPlayer is int.
the ch struct is declared in the "champ.h" header file.

i tried to change the disposition of the header file because i tought it was a problem of order in the delcaration of the struct and the variable, but i don't understand because my function literally return a struct type

here is the main.c file :

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <time.h> 
#include "profile/champ.h" // CREER STRUCT PR MONSTRE ET AVANCER STEPS PR BRANCHE MAGE -> combat -> chemins diverse et histoire -> pareil -> combat

int main() {
  int i = 0;
  char nameInput[20];
  int stepCounter = 0;

  // écran d'acceuil
  i = start();

  
  if (i == 1) { //lancement nouvelle partie
    printf("\033[2J\033[1;1H");
    printf("entrez votre nom :");
    scanf("%s", nameInput);
    struct ch player1;
    player1 = constructPlayer(nameInput);
      i = descS0(player1); // appel de step0, i est le choix de l'user pour la nouvelle étape
    if (i == 1) {
    i =  descSA1(player1); // inclure monstreS1
    }
    else if (i == 2) {
    // i = descSB1(player1);// inclure monstreS1
    }
    else if (i == 3) {
    //  i = descSC1(player1);// inclure monstreS1
    }
    else {
      printf("invalid input, exiting...");
      exit(1);
    }
  }


    
  else if (i == 2) { //chargement sauvegardre
    //load file and jump to step / update stats 
    printf("LOAD SAVED FILE ????");
    exit(1);
  }
  else {
    type("INVALID INPUT, EXITING...\n\n");
    exit(1);
  }
}
```

here is the champ.h header file :

```
#ifndef CHAMP_H
#define CHAMP_H

struct ch { //champion incarné par le joueur
  char name[30];

  //stats 
  int lvl;
  int pv; // health bar
  int ad; // attack damage
  int ap; // magic damage
  int arm; // armor
  int gld; // gold
  int crit;
  int itm[5]; // item register
  int abt[5]; // ability register 
  int spd; // speed -> utile pour fightMech.c/dodge (+ rapide = + de dodge)
  int class; // type de champion, (créer un registre avec sorts/stats de base ??
  
};

#endif
```

and here is the player.c file :

```
#include <string.h> 
#include "champ.h"

struct ch constructPlayer(char nameIn[20]) { 
struct ch player;
strcpy(player.name, nameIn);
player.lvl = 1;
player.pv = 500;
player.ad = 50;
player.ap = 0;
player.crit = 10;
player.arm = 20;
player.gld = 300;
player.spd = 15;
player.class = 0;
  return player;
}
```

thank you for your help !

Comment: Return values are `int` by default, unless the compiler sees a function declaration. Add the line `struct ch constructPlayer(char nameIn[20]);` to your header file.

Comment: It looks like your compiler should be complaining about a call to an undeclared function.  Pay attention to such warnings.

Comment: Note that `#pragma once` is now much preferred over `#ifndef / #define / #endif` for header guards.

Answer (score 6):

You're calling an undeclared function. Such functions are presumed to return an `int`. To fix this problem, add the following to `champ.h`:

```c
struct ch constructPlayer(char nameIn[20]);
```

Make sure to enable your compiler's warnings, as it would have caught this error. With gcc, I use `-Wall -Wextra -Werror -pedantic -pedantic-errors`.